# how to use whyrun Mobx feature with react native?

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I started using `Mobx` as state management for my `react native` app.
I noticed that few components `render` method is being called more than once. I understand its because one of the `observable` is modified or `computed` value is used. [Mobx documentation](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html) mentions **`whyrun`** method to get a hint of why a particular method was run when the observable state is modified. However I did not find any reference to how to use it in react-native to find why the component render was triggered?

Did anyone use `whyrun` feature in react-native with `Mobx`?

Comment: It doesn't work to just call `whyRun()` in the beginning of your `observer` component's render method?

Comment: @tholle I did after your comment. but it did not list observable properties from Store though they were referenced inside `render`.

Comment: That's a bummer. I have never used `whyRun` in react-native myself, so it was just a guess. Do you want to share the store and the component that re-renders multiple times? Maybe it will give some clues.

Answer (score 0):

You can import whyRun with `import { whyRun } from 'mobx'` and use it like you would use in a normal web project. Here are all the exports from MobX that shows the whyRun export:

[MobX Exports](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/a867e87788a3aeb5d03a0a99f8379c13edd6be25/src/mobx.ts)

Hope that helps!